# How to format space around function in JavaScript by ESLint on VSCode?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webstorm, eslint, visual-studio-code

Current VSCode Auto Formatted:

```
co(function* (){})
```

What I want (was set by WebStorm):

```
co(function *(){})
```

What rule should I set in .eslintrc.js or VSCode's settings.json ?

Comment: If you're using ESLint, did you try looking at the rules in their docs? https://eslint.org/docs/rules/generator-star

Comment: So did you try applying that rule with the config you want? *What happened?* Please share your research.

Comment: @NicoNing That's the rule to set.

Comment: Thanks to @jonrsharpe & dave,  I have read the rules  but I missing the "generator-star" because I made mistakes to find rules like "space**" or "function**"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this should do the trick

```
"generator-star-spacing": ["error", {"before": true, "after": false}]
```

for more info visit [here](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/generator-star-spacing)

Comment: Thanks , and I found "Rule 'generator-star' was removed and replaced by: generator-star-spacing"